# Launching the App Store from an iOS application in swift

Tags: swift, store, launch

What is wrong with this code?

```
   @IBAction func Button(sender: AnyObject) {

    NSString *iTunesLink = @"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/id375380948?mt=8";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
}
```

I keep getting several errors such as "Expected Declaration", "Expected an attribute name" etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're mixing up Objective-C and Swift.

If you're using Swift, try:

```
var iTunesLink = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/id375380948?mt=8"
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: iTunesLink)!)
```